# React/enzyme: How to test for subcomponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

This is how my *Messenger* Component looks like. As you can see there is the main component and a list component. The main component is exported as default.
With this everything is working as expected in my application.

**/imports/ui/components/messenger.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Container, Segment, Loader, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class Messenger extends Component {
  static get propTypes () {
    return {
      data: PropTypes.array,
      articleId: PropTypes.string,
      isLoading: PropTypes.bool
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { data, articleId, isLoading } = this.props

    if (isLoading) { return (<Loader active inverted size='massive' className='animated fadeIn' />) }
    if (articleId) { return (<MessengerList data={data} articleId={articleId} />) }

    return (
      <Container>
        <Segment id='' className='m-b-1'>
          <Header as='h1'>Title</Header>
          <MessengerList data={data} />
        </Segment>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

class MessengerList extends Component {
  /* ... */
}

export default Messenger
```

Now I would like to do some unit testing for the main component using enzyme. This is how I am doing it, but the last test is failing as `MessengerList` is not defined. So how should this be done.

```
import React from 'react'
import { expect } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import { Container, Loader } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Messenger from '/imports/ui/components/messenger.jsx'

describe('<Messenger />', () => {
  const defaultProps = {
    data: [],
    articleId: '',
    isLoading: true
  }

  it('should show <Loader /> while loading data', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Messenger {...defaultProps} />);
    expect(wrapper.exists()).to.be.true
    expect(wrapper.find(Loader).length).to.equal(1)
  })
  it('should show <Container /> data has been loaded', () => {
    defaultProps.isLoading = false
    const wrapper = shallow(<Messenger {...defaultProps} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Container).length).to.equal(1)
    expect(wrapper.find(Loader).exists()).to.be.false
  })
  it('should show <MessengerList /> if articleID is given', () => {
    defaultProps.articleID = 'dummy'
    defaultProps.isLoading = false
    const wrapper = shallow(<Messenger {...defaultProps} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(MessengerList).length).to.equal(1)
    expect(wrapper.find(Loader).exists()).to.be.false
  })
})
```

I do not want to change `export default Messenger`

Comment: You have to import the `MessengerList` component in the test. `import MessengerList from '../components/MessengerList.jsx;` Then     `expect(wrapper.find(MessengerList).length).to.equal(1);`

Comment: I can't import it, as it is not exported in the jsx file. Only the main component is exported (as default)

Comment: You have both components in the same file?

Comment: Yes, both components are in the same file. Exactly as posted.

Comment: Are you testing `<Communicator/>` or `<Messenger />`? coz in the test file you're shallow rendering <Communicator />.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. Sorry for that. Updated the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export your MessengerList class ....

```
export class MessengerList extends Component {
  /* ... */
}
```

And then in the test do ....

```
import React from 'react'
import { expect } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import { Container, Loader } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Messenger, { MessengerList } from '/imports/ui/components/messenger.jsx';

describe('<Messenger />', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const defaultProps = {
    data: [],
    articleId: '',
    isLoading: true
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    // render the component once up here in this block. It runs before each test.
    wrapper = shallow(<Messenger {...defaultProps} />);
  });

  it('should show <Loader /> while loading data', () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).to.be.true
    expect(wrapper.find(Loader).length).to.equal(1)
  });

  it('should show <Container /> data has been loaded', () => {
    defaultProps.isLoading = false

    expect(wrapper.find(Container).length).to.equal(1)
    expect(wrapper.find(Loader).exists()).to.be.false
  });

  it('should show <MessengerList /> if articleID is given', () => {
    defaultProps.articleID = 'dummy'
    defaultProps.isLoading = false

    expect(wrapper.find(MessengerList).length).to.equal(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(Loader).exists()).to.be.false
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ideally, you should state that a prop is being modified first ...

```
...
describe('and the data has loaded', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    defaultProps.isLoading = false;
  });

  it('should show <Container /> component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Container).length).to.equal(1)
    expect(wrapper.find(Loader).exists()).to.be.false
  });
});
...
```

Comment: Cannot put the shallow in `beforeEach`, as the `defaultProps` are different for each test.